# ActionCable not transmitting the message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am implementing action cable in rails 5, It is working perfectly on local, But in staging and production, after sending the message to action cable rails logger is thi.

```
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to chats_4: {:id=>"message_97", :message=>"88", :user=>"John", :time=>"15-May-17 06:38 am", :chatroom_id=>4, :file=>nil}
```

But it is not transmitting to the subscribers, browsers console gives error

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://demo.xyz.com/cable.
The connection to wss://demo.xyz.com/cable was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

My environment configuration is given below.

```
 config.action_cable.url = "wss://demo.xyz.com/cable"
 config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['https://demo.xyz.com', 'http://demo.xyz.com']
```

I am hosting the application in passenger + nginx

```
location /cable {
          passenger_app_group_name xyz_websocket;
           passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
         }
```

My nginx log says

```
2017/05/15 06:43:30 [error] 13412#0: *675 open() "/home/test/apps/xyz/current/public/cable" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 103.xix.204.xx, server: https://demo.xyz.com, request: "GET /cable HTTP/1.1", host: "demo.xyz.com"
```

Help me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Can read more about the setup [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/action_cable_integration/) , but I'd make sure you are mounting the cable server separately - it sounds like " Passenger actually insists on running it as a separate process"

Comment: I have implemented the same